# How to put SwiftUI button into NSToolbar?

Tags: cocoa, swiftui, nswindow, appkit, nstoolbar

This is how SwiftUI can be inserted into `NSToolbar` using an accessory view controller:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

var hostingView = NSHostingView(rootView:
  ZStack {
    Color.clear
    HStack {
      Text("Hey")
      Text("SwiftUI")
    }
  }
  .padding()
  .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
)
hostingView.frame.size = hostingView.fittingSize

let titlebarAccessory = NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController()
titlebarAccessory.view = hostingView
titlebarAccessory.layoutAttribute = .trailing

let mask: NSWindow.StyleMask = [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable]
let window = NSWindow(
  contentRect: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
  styleMask: mask, backing: .buffered, defer: false)
window.center()
window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: Color(.windowBackgroundColor))
window.toolbar = .init()
window.titleVisibility = .hidden
window.addTitlebarAccessoryViewController(titlebarAccessory)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = window.contentView?.superview
```

The code above does work:

[image]

If we insert a button however:

```
HStack {
  Text("Hey")
  Button(action: {}) {
    Text("SwiftUI")
  }
}
```

It would not work as expected:

[image]

Any suggestions?

**P. S. This is a working solution:**

```
HStack {
  Text("Hey")
    .offset(x: 0, y: -1)
  Button(action: {}) {
    Text("SwiftUI")
      .offset(x: 0, y: -7)
  }
}
.font(.caption)
```

[image]

Comment: Definitely not a good answer, but you can use `.padding(EdgeInsets(top: -7, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))` on the Text in the button. Definitely buggy though.

Comment: @LucasDerraugh This is a great answer actually. Could you please submit it?

Comment: @Vadim I am curious why you are using a `ZStack`.

Comment: @BijoyThangaraj It feels less weird than H or V in this particular case 

Comment: I've noticed that apparently this bug does NOT occur when the end user makes the window full screen, making all workarounds (ugly as they are) unusable... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer per request. Not necessarily a reliable solution but as a workaround you can use

```
Text("SwiftUI")
  .padding(EdgeInsets(top: -7, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
```

or `.offset` on the Text in the button. No guarantees on how long that will last as a solution.

Comment: This may still not work when/if the user makes the window full screen, unfortunately. Also, the -7 value is "variable" and depends on the height of the actual view.

Comment: Like I said, more of a workaround rather than a solution. I was requested to post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The way I eventually handled it (making it work also when the user makes the window full screen AND regardless of the height* of the content) is below. Note that I'm using Toolbar view in an NSHostingView within NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController of a macOS app built with most recent Xcode version (obviously, on macOS Catalina).

Important things: *you still need to setup a fixed height for the frame (but at least you won't rely to the "variable" -7) and offset to top by half of the actual height ONLY when there is safe area top inset (in full screen mode, apparently, it isn't) and therefore GeometryReader is a must:

```
struct Toolbar : View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Text("1st row")
                Text("2nd row")
            }
            .offset(y: geometry.safeAreaInsets.top > 0 ? -geometry.size.height / 2 : 0)
        }
        .frame(height: 42)
    }
}
```

and where window is created:

```
let toolbar = NSHostingView(rootView: Toolbar())
toolbar.frame.size = toolbar.fittingSize
let toolbarController = NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController()
toolbarController.view = toolbar
window.addTitlebarAccessoryViewController(toolbarController)
```

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar item has more vertical space. To fix that use Spacer view it will push the button to the top:

```swift
VStack {
  Button(action: {}) {
    Text("Text")
  }.frame(height: 22)

  Spacer()
}
```

Comment: This works, except if there is an actual toolbar button below the accessory view, it cannot be accessed by the accessibility APIs (as you can see by running the Accessibility Inspector on it), which prevents assistive devices from being able to access those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that applying `PlainButtonStyle` to the button helps.
Default style is doing some weird magic that is breaking the layout in NSToolbar.